# Stationarity Interrupted Time Series

Tags: time-series, arima

I have a university time series of 48 observations reflecting the area of land undergoing conversion from natural to non-natural for every quarter over a 12 year period. There is a great deal of variation per quarter, but there appears to be a general trend towards larger areas being lost in later years.

I am testing whether a change in policy affected the rate of change through Interrupted Time Series. Initially I just applied standard segmented regression techniques, but have been confused by attempting to address non-stationarity.

I originally attempted to decompose the data, but only removed the trend that represents he issue I was trying to analyse. I am ultimately confused as to how I could ever create a stationary time series, which enables analysis of whether the change in policy resulted in the trend changing.

Additionally the data cannot be made stationary through differencing. Are there any methods that can be used on non-stationary data without the need to transform first? I have looked at ARIMA, but am just confused at present.

I guess I don't really understand how you could assess a change in underlying trends fro  stationary data??

An anyone help shed some light on this?